# Is changing a live Community Ad image frowned upon?

Tags: discussion, advertising

We're promoting the [Woodworking Q&A site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61927/woodworking?referrer=KiPtL-stfbZEcOlY9VldUw2) through the DIY community ads. As you can see on the proposal site, when the ad went live at the beginning of September there was a big boost in the number of followers.

At this point, the proposal no longer needs followers, just questions with a score of 10 or more. [I've made a new ad](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/985/12529) that hopefully highlights this need. I was going to replace the original ad with this new one but I hesitated because a) I wasn't sure this ad was *better* and b) I wasn't sure if that was fair.  DIYers that voted on the current version of the ad may not approve of the new version and I felt like I'd we switching it out under their feet.

I should note that I have updated the live ad once, but in that case the message of the ad was the same and I felt the quality was unquestionably better.

So what do you think is the better option,

1. Try to get 6 votes on the new ad and run them both or
2. Replace the image of the live ad with the new version

Comment: Could someone with 300+ rep create and add an [advertising] tag as per the instructions on the [community-ads] tag wiki excerpt

Comment: Advertising tag added, I'll see if I can find another question or two that matches so the cleanup bots don't remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question should bring enough attention to the new ad, to get the required votes.  You could also post a link in chat, to make sure folks see it.  Just don't expect much attention until Monday or Tuesday, when everyone gets back to their jobs.